# I have a BMW E30 the check light for brake & registration comes on & bulbs are all OK

Tags: bmw, lights

BMW E30 Convertible check light for brake & registration coming on to indicate that the bulbs are blown but all bulbs are correct and not blown

Comment: Have you checked *all the bulbs*?

Comment: What's the year? Newer BMWs have reset procedures for the brake pad life, registration renewal, and a bunch of other service related things. They will also illuminate the brake light if the pads are low.

Comment: Some cars have double filament brake lights, if one of the filament blows the lights still glow, but an error may show. Also check the center brake light if your car has one. What does the light look like anyways, maybe it means something else?

Comment: Its a BMW E30 1989 convertible and I can't find any info on this problem

Comment: All the bulbs have 1 filament in each and a separate bulb for each function they all have the correct bulbs, there is no high stop light